# Is there a way to export a pandas Dataframe to an Excel Sheet keeping the Dataframe's float format?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

my goal is to export a pandas dataframe to an excel file keeping the format of the dataframe.
Here is the code snipet to create and format the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(100000, 1000, 5), 'B': 'line'})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('CDEF'))],axis=1)

path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "styled.xlsx")
        
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet',header=True, index=False, startrow=0, startcol=0)

my_format = writer.book.add_format({'align': 'center',
                                               'num_format': '#,##0.00', 
                                               'bg_color': '#FFFFFF', 
                                               'fg_color': '#000000'})
for col in (0, 6):
    writer.sheets['sheet'].set_column(col, col, None, my_format)

writer.save()
```

This is the dataframe in Jupyter notebook (this is exactly what I wanted to see in the excel sheet):
[Dataframe with float formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4LNG.png)

But this is the Excel file that I got when I run the code above:
[Excel sheet output with unformatted floats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIKBq.png)

**Can anybody help getting the desired format of the dataframe into the Excel file?
I already tried doing this with openpyxl but it seems that it does not format the area where the dataframe is sitting, just the rest of the Excel sheet.**

Comment: did the excelwriter worked with you? can you please give me a feedback if it did or not

Comment: thanks for the prompt response @basilisk but it is not working as expected, I will edit the post with the code I tried to run now.

Comment: can you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: Have you tried to run my code? It's reproducible, it will save an Excel file in your desktop without any float format or white background as it was intended to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the ExcelWriter for this:

```
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/your_excel.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(excel_writer, index=False, sheet_name='mysheet')
book  = excel_writer.book
sheet = excel_writer.sheets['mysheet']
excel_format = book.add_format({'num_format': '0.000'})
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, excel_format)  # Adds formatting to column C
excel_writer.save()
```

Also take a look [here in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)